# How is IValidate.GetInvalidRules supposed to work?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, validation

we are currently trying to programmatically  validate features against geodatabase-defined rules. This includes attribute rules as well as connectivity and relationship rules.

We have consulted the documentation for [IValidate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IValidate_Interface/0025000009zn000000/), [IValidation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000009zt000000) and the [Validating features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000z3000000) article on EDN to learn how it's done.

After setting up the appropriate connectivity rules, invocation of the [Validate Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Validating_features_and_relationships_in_ArcMap/001t000000mp000000/) in ArcMap correctly yields the number of invalid features in a selection. If I select a single feature, invocation of this command correctly displays what is wrong about that particular feature in a message box.

Now, calling [IValidate.Validate](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Validate_Method/002500000m04000000/) on that feature works as well. Its return value indicates that the feature is indeed invalid, and the error message is identical to that displayed by the Validate Features command in ArcMap. However, calling this method has two disadvantages which are problematic for our purposes:

1. It performs the validation in a short-circuit manner. As soon as one of the assigned rules is invalid, it stops evaluating the remaining rules. We need to evaluate all the rules so that we can display the violations at once.
2. It provides the error information as a string. For our purposes, we would ideally like to examine the information in a more structured way, which means we need to access the [IRule](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetInvalidRules_Method/0025000009zq000000/)s that turned out to be invalid.

So, this is where [IValidate.GetInvalidRules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetInvalidRules_Method/0025000009zq000000/) comes into play. The documentation for this method states:

> The GetInvalidRules method returns an enumerator of rules that are currently violated by the row.

which is exactly what we are after. However, the enumeration returned by this method does not seem to ever contain anything. What is particularly weird is that:

1. Calling `IValidate.Validate` on a feature yields the appropriate validation error message as expected.
2. Calling `IValidate.GetInvalidRules` on the very same feature always returns an empty enumeration as if no connectivity or relationship rules were invalid. (It does not matter whether the call is made within an edit session or not.)

How can I validate a row against all the assigned geodatabase rules at once? Has anyone used `IValidate.GetInvalidRules` successfully?

**UPDATE:** `IValidate.GetInvalidRules` seems to return invalid rules which pertain to attributes. However, invalid network connectivity rules are still never returned from this method.

Comment: i think you meant IValidate.GetInvalidRules ..

Comment: is there a quick way to create an error in connectivity for a feature manually?

Comment: @vinayan: Yes, but one needs to define the geometric network's connectivity rules first. These are typically set through ArcCatalog. It is very easy to set up, e.g., a rule where a junction must be connected to exactly one edge, and subsequently violate that rule by creating two adjacent edges.

Comment: Did you try calling IEnumRule.Reset before calling Next()?

Comment: @Kirk: As with every enumeration in ArcObjects, yes.

Comment: Did you try instantiating an [ObjectClassValidator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ObjectClassValidatorClass_Class/002500000n1v000000/) and calling IValidation2 methods (ValidateSelection, Validate and ValidateSet)?

Comment: @Kirk: I did not try calling IValidation2 method on the ObjectClassValidator class, but I did try it on a particular FeatureClass. It works, but none of the methods offered by IValidation2 really solve my primary problem - that is, how to get all rules which are invalid for a single row at once, including network connectivity and relationship rules.

Comment: @Kirk: It seems that IValidate.GetInvalidRules is there to do just that, but it simply never returns any violated rules except attribute rules (e.g. a field value outside a domain). On the other hand, IValidate.Validate does return connectivity and relationship rules violations, but its fatal problem is the short-circuit evaluation it performs, which means you cannot get the list of all violations at once. I'm sorry that maybe wasn't completely clear in my post.

Comment: What if you QI the featureclass for IValidation and got a List of IRules.  Then for each rule in the list instantiate an ObjectClassValidator and AddRule for just one rule to it.  Since each ObjectClassValidator has only one rule in it, seems like you should be able to call Validate (indirectly) on each rule and determine which rules are in violation.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that. Seemed like it could be the way to go but unfortunately, cocreating an ObjectClassValidator instance and calling IValidation.AddRule on that instance crashes ArcMap. There isn't any documentation on the purpose and usage ofObjectClassValidator. Have you used this way?

Comment: It's been a while, but I was on a project using arc8.0 and ran into this same issue.  I can't remember if we ever resolved it.  Maybe ObjectClassValidator is a singleton?  In that case maybe try validating each rule one at a time (AddRule,Validate,DeleteRule).

Comment: It crashes upon calling pretty much every method on IValidation, including AddRule, Rules property, Validate etc. I've already contacted our local Esri distributor about how to approach the issue with IValidate.GetInvalidRules so I guess I'll see if they can come up with something. To me, it seems like a bug.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but you tried calling Validate first and then followed that call by getinvalidrules right?

Comment: @Ragi: Yes, I did try that. I now have official confirmation that it is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ESRI support, this behavior is indeed a bug.